# How to stop Jackson ObjectReader overwriting existing data

Tags: java, kotlin, jackson

We have a Jackson ObjectReader that is overwriting any original data if it is missing from the json update request.

This is what the data structure looks like:

```
data class Model(
  val fieldTypeA: FieldTypeA? = null,
)

data class FieldTypeA(
  val valueA: String? = null,
  val valueB: String? = null,
)
```

We then read an existing value from a database so that `fieldTypeA.valueA = "Test"`

```
val existingModel = repository.findById(id).getOrNull()
```

Then this line reads the existing data into an ObjectReader:

```
val readerForUpdating: ObjectReader = CustomMapper.readerForUpdating(existingEntity)
```

This is where the problem occurs. The `readValue` overwrites the `fieldTypeA.valueA` after this line is executed with a `jsonRequest`:

```
val updatedRequest: Model = readerForUpdating.readValue(jsonRequest)
```

`jsonRequest`:

```
{"fieldTypeA":{"valueB":"I am value B"}}
```

The `existingEntity` object now only contains `fieldTypeA.valueB`, with `fieldTypeA.valueA` getting overwritten with `null`.

Is there a way to tell Jackson not to overwrite when a value is missing from the JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed my own problem in the following way, in case it helps someone in the future.

There was a new feature introduced in [Jackson 2.9](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/jackson/json-merge-annotation.html) which allows deep merging. To do this, the relevant property needs to be tagged with `@JsonMerge`.

So in my example question above, the `Model` object would be changed like this:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonMerge

data class Model(
  @JsonMerge
  val fieldTypeA: FieldTypeA? = null,
)
```

This means if the original object contains a field with a value, it does not get overwritten to `null` when the new json comes in.

Answer (score 0):

`readerForUpdating(obj)` only promises to use the root object you pass

> Deserialization occurs normally except that the root-level value in JSON is not used for instantiating a new object; instead give updateable object is used as root

whereas `fieldTypeA.valueA` is an inner object.

It works on a shallow object:

```
val existingModel = FieldTypeA(valueA = "A")
println(existingModel)
val readerForUpdating: ObjectReader = MAPPER.readerForUpdating(existingModel)
val jsonRequest = "{\"valueB\":\"I am value B\"}"
val updatedRequest: FieldTypeA = readerForUpdating.readValue(jsonRequest)
println(updatedRequest)
```

produces

```
FieldTypeA(valueA=A, valueB=null)
FieldTypeA(valueA=A, valueB=I am value B)
```

It's hard to see how you could develop a feature like `readerForUpdating()` which would know which fields to adjust in a deep object graph.  If the incoming object's object's field had a value, should that indicate an overwrite? but not if they come as nulls?

If I had to do this way myself, I might approach it this way:

1. read the incoming JSON into a traditional JSONObject then walk the keys and set the properties on the target object
2. For setting properties you could use old school [Apache Commons BeanUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.4/apidocs/index.html) tool, but I am not sure that that is maintained and it has had some vulnerabilities issues, so you could look at [Spring's BeanWrapperImpl](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/BeanWrapperImpl.html)